# Problem with reading/writing plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, plist

I have an MSMutableArray that contains many NSDictionaries. A dictionary is just an NSString with a key "symbol".

I am writing my array to a plist:

```
+ (void)writeObjectToPList:(id)myData {  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mobile-watchlist.plist"];
    [myData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

How can I read this back as an array?

Comment: in which xcode you are working?? I am asking because by default in xcode 4.x i encountered same problem which then i solved by removing extra <dict> tag inside which all my array items where there.... Try to edit in text editor and see if that is the problem

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can't write or can't read, or both? Got any error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file back like this --

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```